# iOS UITextView auto scroll from top to down

Tags: ios, textview

I am new to iPhone development .Need help.I am developing iPhone app which contain UITextview,I want count the textview's words not use textview.text.length, just words count. 
and I want the textview auto scroll in one minute

```
 -(IBAction)startbutton:(id)sender{
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                                                 target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(updateScroll)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
    self.startingTime = [NSDate date];
}

-(void)updateScroll
{
    double noSeconds = (double) [self.startingTime timeIntervalSinceNow] /60;
    frtextview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,noSeconds * frtextview.contentSize.height);
}
```

Above code can auto scroll, but the textview scroll from down to top,Iwant it from top to down,I hope you can help me find which code have problem.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSScanner could be used to do a words count, scan for white-space and count number of occurrences should work.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you simply negate your contentOffset I would think that would reverse the direction of your scrolling.

```
frtextview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -(noSeconds * frtextview.contentSize.height));
```

Here's a simple example:

```
-(unsigned) wordCount: (NSString *) textString 
{
NSScanner *wordScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: textString];
NSCharacterSet *whiteSpace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];

unsigned wordCount = 0;
while ([wordScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet: whiteSpace intoString: nil])
{
wordCount++;
}

return wordCount;
}
```

I got the original code here where there is a lot more detailed discussion:

http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-26871.html

Comment: Thank you for you help.I only  know NSScanner Class is available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.Can I use it in iOS ?

Comment: I have used it in my iOS apps.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use NSScanner to count words? Or sample code?Thank you for you help!

Comment: I added some code and a link for you.  Of course there is a lot more you could do, depending on how fancy you want to get.